# How do I make a PyQt QLineEdit widget narrower than the default size of 17 x's when using QT Designer?

Tags: layout, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlineedit

When I put Qt widgets in a `QHBoxLayout` layout using QT Designer, there seems to be a minimum width for `QLineEdit` widgets of 17 x's, at least if this is the current source code:

https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp

I cannot find a way to make PyQt5 lay those widgets out so they will be narrower than this default, but still change size if the font is changed.

As an example, a `QComboBox` will be automatically laid out so that it is just wide enough to display the longest text that is entered as a possible value.  If the longest text entered for a combobox in Designer is 5 characters, the combobox will be laid out as quite narrow compared to the minimum `QLineEdit` width.  How can I configure a `QLineEdit` with a number of characters so that it is always wide enough for that many characters, whatever the font is set to, and no wider, using just QT Designer?  I know in Designer I can enter `maxLength`, which will limit the maximum number of characters that can be entered/displayed, but that setting of course has no effect on the layout.

I have some text boxes that will never have more than 5 characters in them, for example, and the layout with Designer makes them at least 3 times wider than I will ever need.  This is using the default "Expanding" horizontal policy, but I have tried many combinations of horizontal policy and values for minimum size or base size.  I want to allow for people to have different font sizes, so I cannot safely set a maximum pixel size and I cannot safely set a fixed horizontal size.  The handling for `QComboBox`es is precisely what I want for `QLineEdit`s.

This is all in python using the latest versions of PyQt5 available on Pip, pyqt5 5.15.6 and pyqt5-qt5 5.15.2.

Comment: This isn't possible directly from Designer, but you could create a subclass of QLineEdit that supports that through a `sizeHint()` override or by means of `setMaximumWidth()` if that's what you want. Then promote the line edits in Designer so that the UI will use your class.

Comment: @musicamante Can you do this in Python or do you need to do this in C++?  That is, would a Python subclass of QLineEdit that overrode sizeHintI() work?  Could I add such a Python class to QT Designer so it could be used as a QLineEdit?

Comment: it's perfectly doable and relatively easy in Python. I'm not at home right now, but I could provide a solution in a couple of hours if you cannot find it on your own or nobody else will. You can add the class as a promoted widget in Designer, which means that in there it will "look" as a standard QLineEdit, but the actual final behavior will be of your subclass when run in Python. You could create a Designer plugin, but I don't think it's worth it, considering that it's not easy to do set up one you haven't ever done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size hint of QLineEdit is computed considering various aspects, most of them using private functions that are not exposed to the API, and the "x" count is hardcoded, meaning that this cannot be achieved directly from Designer, and can only be done through subclassing.

While we could try to mimic its behavior to implement a custom character size, I believe it is unnecessary for simple cases, so I simplified the concept by taking the default size hint and adapting the width based on the *difference* between the custom character hint and the default 17 "x" count.

```py
class CharHintLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    _charHint = 17
    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int)
    def charHint(self):
        return self._charHint

    @charHint.setter
    def charHint(self, chars):
        chars = max(1, chars)
        if self._charHint != chars:
            self._charHint = chars
            self.updateGeometry()

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        super().changeEvent(event)
        if event.type() in (event.FontChange, event.StyleChange):
            self.updateGeometry()

    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = super().sizeHint()
        if self._charHint != 17:
            # the 17 char width is hardcoded in Qt and there is no way to
            # retrieve it, it might change in the future, so, just to be safe,
            # we always set an arbitrary minimum based on half the height hint
            charSize = self.fontMetrics().horizontalAdvance('x')
            hint.setWidth(max(hint.height() // 2, hint.width() + 
                charSize * (self._charHint - 17)))
        return hint


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from random import randrange
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(test)
    for i in range(5):
        charHint = randrange(5, 15)
        le = CharHintLineEdit(charHint=charHint, placeholderText=str(charHint))
        layout.addWidget(le)
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

With the above code, you can use the custom widget in Designer by adding a standard QLineEdit and promoting it with the class name and relative python file (without the file extension) as header. You can also set the `charHint` as a dynamic property in Designer, and it will be properly set for the widget when the UI is loaded.

Comment: Thank you!  That was awesome!  It would have taken me a long time to figure this out.  Qt and PyQt are powerful but the learning curve is ferocious.  I've seen lots of people asking this question when I searched but I never found any answers.  I wish I could give more than a thank you, up vote, and check mark for accepted answer.

Comment: @Eddie Well, you're very welcome! And, yes, Qt has a tough learning curve: its tools and python bindings may lead you to think that it's easy at first, but, after those nice and cool beginner steps, the more you learn, the more you understand you know nothing but a fraction of it. But there resides its power, in my opinion: it's a strong and extremely extendable toolkit, and, as such, you must take your time to know -and make peace with- it. Btw, I finally decided to fix my profile, so if you are *that* eager to give more than what you already did, now there's a nice donation link there ;-)

Comment: Definitely worth it!  Thanks for setting that up.  Donation sent.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Eddie Well, thank *you* for your kind gesture :-)